# Has the band Crossfade retired?

Tags: rock, bands, where-are-they-now

I have not seen Crossfade release a record since *We All Bleed*, and they have not updated their Facebook and Twitter pages at all.  I also do not see any fan group updates or new merchandise or tour dates or anything announced for at least the past 12 months.  Has Crossfade retired?

Answer (score 1):

According to [their Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/crossfadeband/?fref=nf), as of a month and a half ago (March 13th), they are still together and planning to make new music. Lead singer Ed Sloan posted the following (emphasis mine).

> What's up peeps!? Ed here. I just wanted to poke my head in here, say hi and clear some things up for any of you that thought we dropped off the face of it. :) I know it's been a while and I hope you all will forgive us for the silence. **Yes, we are still together** and all very well. **And YES, there will be more music!** When? Not sure yet. Still at it. Know that you will be the first to hear about it! We love and miss you!
>   PEACE!
>   Ed

This is the most recent post or news activity I've been able to find, but I'd imagine they're still together and just taking their time in coming up with a new album.